# Bash getopts multiple flags with single required parameter

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to make getopts accept multiple flags with a single argument. For example.

Flags: Children: a - Adam  b - Beth c - Cathy d - Duncan

Required parameter: ice cream flavor

(not what my script really does, but easiest to spell out this way)

What I can do right now:

```
./flavor -a chocolate

./flavor -c chocolate
```

What I'd like to do:

```
./flavor -acd chocolate
```

Rather than the only thing I can get it to do so far:

```
./flavor -a chocolate -c chocolate -d chocolate
```

Every variation I've tried with getopts either doesn't see the parameter at all or requires it after every single flag declaration. I feel like I'm missing something obvious that will give me the "aha" moment, but I'm not seeing it on my own. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

============================================

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:d:" opt; do
  case $opt in
        a)
          do stuff with $OPTARG
         ;;
        b) 
          do stuff with $OPTARG
         ;;
        c)
          do stuff with $OPTARG
         ;;
        d)
          do stuff with $OPTARG
         ;;
        :)
         echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
         exit 1
         ;;
  esac
done
```

============================================

My apologies if this is a really dumb question and thank you for your time.

Comment: You aren't missing anything; there isn't a way to specify that a single argument should be shared by all the options in a group.

Comment: I believe you can't do that, but I may be wrong. With `./flavor -acd` **a** will consume **cd** as its `$OPTARG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacking options that require arguments is not supported by *getopts*.  You can only stack options that do not take arguments.

To do what you propose, a lot more complication in the argument processing is required.  Essentially you would have to pre-process the options to find out where the non-option arguments begin.  This is not particularly beautiful or recommended, but this does literally what you asked for without requiring an additional option:

```
_GETOPTS=":abcd"
while getopts "${_GETOPTS}" opt
do
  case $opt in
        abcd)
         :
         ;;
        \?)
         echo "Unsupported option (-${OPTARG})" >&2
         exit 1
         ;;
  esac
done
eval "FIRSTARG=\${${OPTIND}}"
if [ -z "${FIRSTARG}" ]
then
   echo "Flavor argument required."
   exit 1
fi
OPTIND=1
while getopts "${_GETOPTS}" opt
do
  case $opt in
        a)
         echo do a stuff with ${FIRSTARG}
         ;;
        b)
         echo do b stuff with ${FIRSTARG}
         ;;
        c)
         echo do c stuff with ${FIRSTARG}
         ;;
        d)
         echo do d stuff with ${FIRSTARG}
         ;;
  esac
done
```

Results:

```
$ ./flavor -acd chocolate
do a stuff with chocolate
do c stuff with chocolate
do d stuff with chocolate
```

One can access other arguments after the first non-option argument, but that would take a bit more work.

Note that handling the same set of options in multiple *getopts* statements is prone to create long term maintenance issues in that it might be too easy for the options handled by the two *case* statements to get out of sync.

Comment: Thank you. This gets me about 90% of the way there. I just have to figure out how to make the parameter required now so that it can't be left out.

Comment: Insert just before the second while statement something along the lines of `if [ -z "${FIRSTARG}" ]; then echo Flavor argument required; exit 1; fi`

Comment: Yep. Works like a charm! Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit tweaky way of doing it would be :

```
 #!/bin/bash
while getopts ":abcdf:" opt; do
case $opt in
f)
FLAVOUR="$OPTARG"

if [ ${ADAM_IN:-0} -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "Adam gets $FLAVOUR"
  ADAM_IN=0
fi
if [ ${BETH_IN:-0} -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "Beth gets $FLAVOUR"
  BETH_IN=0
fi
if [ ${CATHY_IN:-0} -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "Cathy gets $FLAVOUR"
  CATHY_IN=0
fi
if [ ${DUNCAN_IN:-0} -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "Duncan gets $FLAVOUR"
  DUNCAN_IN=0
fi
;;
a)
  ADAM_IN=1
;;
b)
  BETH_IN=1
;;
c)
  CATHY_IN=1
;;
d)
  DUNCAN_IN=1
;;
:)
echo "invalid argument" 2>/dev/null
exit 1
;;
esac
done
```

Save the script as `ice_cream_allocator` and run it like:

```
$ ./ice_cream_allocator -abcf"Chocolate" -df"Vanila" -cf"Strawberry"
```

**Output**

```
Adam gets Chocolate
Beth gets Chocolate
Cathy gets Chocolate
Duncan gets Vanila
Cathy gets Strawberry
```

Well I have a soft-corner for Cathy so giving her two flavours ;)

Comment: I see what you're doing here, but when I de-simplify what my script is actually doing (ie, not ice cream), this won't be feasible. I do thank you for taking the time to reply and offer assistance.

Comment: @Mathaen : You're welcome, and good luck with what you wish to do. :-)